# Cannot Toggle TAFJ Project Nature in Temenos R19 Design Studio

Tags: eclipse

I am using R19 Design Studio, but cannot find the 'Toggle TAFJ Project Nature' when right-clicking. Nor do I have the TAFJ perspective available.

I also tried to place the plugins available in R19 in the Dropins folder of Design Studio, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropins folder in Design Studio (DS) should have a file named "tafj.link", which points to a working TAFJ installation, like this:

```
path=c:/Temenos/R18ModelBank/TAFJ
```

Note: the path should contain slashes "/", not backslashes "\".

Also, did you copy the t24-binaries-xxxxxxxxxx.zip file inside the Design Studio folder before starting it? Once you do this, DS will ask you to install the latest t24-binaries.

Comment: DS took quite some time before launching, but managed to get the TAFJ Perspective.

Comment: Yes, t24-binaries-xxxxx.zip is quite large, usually around 1GB. Sometimes you also need to launch DS with -clean option, then it also takes a while.